# Displaying Received Push Notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification

I'm implementing [this](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app) codes , according to [Google Developers Guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm).

Everything is ok , I can receive notification datas successfully.

If you check GCMIntentService.java file 70th line, it's echoing this lines to LogCat :

```
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Working... 1/5 @ 8656981
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Working... 2/5 @ 8657982
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Working... 3/5 @ 8658983
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Working... 4/5 @ 8659983
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Working... 5/5 @ 8660984
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Completed work @ 8661985
 I/GCM Demo(6653): Received: Bundle[{msg=messagehere, from=SENDERIDHERE, android.support.content.wakelockid=3, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]
```

So my device is receiving notification data, but there is no visible notification in device's status bar. Nothing happening.

Can you tell me why these push notifications aren't displayed on my device, only in LogCat?

**UPDATES**

1. [Manifest file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8707490/)
2. This is my sendNotification() method :

   ```
   private void sendNotification(String msg) {
       mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
           this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

       PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
           new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

       NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
       .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
       .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
       .bigText(msg))
       .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
       mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
   }
   ```

Comment: Post your code where you are creating a notification (`sendNotification` in the code you linked).

Comment: Try using this `(int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);` in place of `NOTIFICATION_ID` at line number 106. Just a wild guess. Also try using full path for intent service class in the manifest file.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 , tried them. Nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try using full path for `GCMIntentService.java` ?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 yes. `<service android:name="com.xyz.example.GcmIntentService" android:enabled="true" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this method.... This one is working for me. Although its almost same as yours...

```
private void sendNotification(String msg)
{
    int uniqueId = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueId,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Hello")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Hello"))
            .setContentText("This is your notification content")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(uniqueId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Waking up the phone is quite different matter. You can do it using a WakeLock this way:

When you set your notification:

```
WakeLock screenOn = ((PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "test");
screenOn.acquire();
```

And yes, DON'T FORGET TO release the wakelock when you don't need it anymore (may be after 5 seconds or on tap of notificaton; as required per your need):

```
screenOn.release();
```

Comment: Difference is adding flags. Default example is little old and hasn't been updated. Could you accept this as your answer if it solved your problem? :D

Comment: Why it's not awaking phone if it's locked ?

(Ofcourse i'll accept it, but before it I have some questions :) )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (in your android manifest file) that the service may not have been enabled

Please try replacing `<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />` with:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

Comment: `android:enabled="true"` is not required for simple notification. works good without it.

Comment: No? Interesting. I'm using API 19 and I had issues without `enabled` included in the manifest.

Comment: Cause must have been something else. It works without that... :)